# Oracle : Format the decimal number for display

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display a list of decimal number with using to_char function in oracle, but I don't know how to do..

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_CHAR(-11111.1,'fm000000000D999999999'),'^\.','0.')  FROM dual;
```

Result:

```
-000011111.1
```

May I know how to print out the standard pattern of decimal list like below? You may expect the decimal number of range is '999999.999999'. Thanks.

```
Negative decimal number --------------------

-000011111.1  --> -11111.1
-0.1          --> -0.1
-0000.1       --> -0.1
-1.1000       --> -1.1


Positive decimal number ---------------------

000011111.1  --> 11111.1
0.1          --> 0.1
0000.1       --> 0.1
1.1000       --> 1.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using this kind of formatting with `to_char` and had no problem with it yet. 
`'FM99999999999999990.0'` 
The key is to add a zero before the point.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the answer is good, but there still have zero remaining.

SELECT TO_CHAR(-01.1000, 'FM99999999999999990.0000') FROM DUAL;

Comment: @LoAlex I updated my answer leaving only one zero after the point, doesn't it fit to your requirements? If not please specify in what cases it works wrong

Comment: @LoAlex the trailing zero can be changed depending on what you want. If you want  four zeros after the point you have to change the trailing zeros from one to four and vice a versa. In your comment you wrote 4 trailing zeros.

Comment: Okay. But one more thing, what i got from your comments is i think you understand the formatting a bit wrong,(sorry if i am being mistaken). When you write the formatting pattern you specify the way you want the number to be, not the way it appears before formatting. And if this really solved the problem please accept as an answer.

Comment: Sorry that I still cannot vote up your answer because of I only have 13 reputation. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT rtrim(TO_CHAR(NUM,'99999999990D9999999999'),'0.')  FROM 
(SELECT -000011111.1 AS NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT -0.1         AS NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT -0000.1      AS NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT -1.1000      AS NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 000011111.1  AS NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 0.1          AS NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 1            AS NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 0000.1       AS NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 1.1000       AS NUM FROM dual);
```

Comment: I have changed to like this...
RTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(1.0,'99999999990D0000'),'0'),'.')

Comment: Yes, I missed this case.
Fixed query. No need in additional RTRIM, one may trim both characters.
And added case in list.